# Adding 3 databases of data together but not merging

Tags: business-objects

We are at a critical juncture with a BO development project and this element is critical.

Basically we have 3 universes relating to library services, all with transaction data for the year. The first lists all the loans made, the second has all the computer sessions listed, and the third shows all the eformat loans made. I want to join these together and have a report as below, so all the records from the three universes would be listed out under three common headings below. If I was doing this in Excel I'd be copying and pasting each dataset underneath each other.

Customer ID | Date of transaction | Library used

Is this possible? Everything I've seen shows datasets being merged, but this is not what I want to do, I want all the unique transactions from which I can build a picture of how our libraries are used.

My colleague has shown me the merge function but I don't want to combine the data, I want them all in a long list so I can see every transaction

I currently use crystal reports for one of the databases so starting to wonder if this might handle combining datasets into one a bit better.

Comment: Not sure. There might be better answers to be found on Bob in the universe section https://bobj-board.org/c/semantic-layer-universe-designer/136

Comment: There is an option in BO to view the query as SQL query. I'm not sure what kind of underlying database you are using, but you might be able to use a 'UNION' expression.